# jQuery/CSS flip Animation

Tags: jquery, css-transforms

I'm searching for a jquery Plugin or a way to do the following animation with css transforms.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2hjD.png

I have searched with google but all I could find was this standard flip animation. But I want the flip animation to start in the middle, as seen on the picture above.

Thank you!

Comment: is this supposed to be some sort of circular flip book?

Comment: Basically just two images. An image in the front, an image in the back and the flip animation that shows alternating the first and second.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my HTML & CSS code that I`ve used on my project and it is supported in all browsers includin IE10+

```
<style>
.flippBox {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index: 101;
    height:50%;
    width:50%;
}
.flippBox > div {
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}
.flippBox .front{
    z-index: 101;
    -moz-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
    transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
    background:red;
}
.flippBox .back{
    -moz-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(-180deg);
    transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(-180deg);
    background:#049045;
}
.flippBox:hover .front {
    -webkit-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
    transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
}
.flippBox:hover .back{
    -moz-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0);
    -webkit-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0);
    transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
}
</style>

<div class="flippBox"><div class="front">text</div><div class="back">text</div></div>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxqwwN I can't get this to work here... Have you forgotten some code?

Comment: it`s because .flippBox has width and height in percent, try add pixels, like width:300px;height:300px instead what I give it (height:50%;width:50%;) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEqmvb and go with mouse over that box

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I am searching for.. Please see my image attached in the question.